# LinkedIn Companies API pagination is broken

Tags: linkedin-api

According to https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#list_companies there are `start` and `count` parameters, but apparently `start` is ignored.
So I'm not able to fetch more than a first 100 companies.

Also I've tried to use API V2 endpoint organizationalEntityAcls, since it allows me to fetch all companies. But it's missing number of followers and have URN instead of logo URL, which I wasn't able to convert with projection params.

Is there any workaround for fetching full list of companies?

Answer (score 0):

that API is for getting all companies that your are a administrator of.
are you sure you are using the correct API for what you want to achieve ?

> The API calls listed on this page require the member to be an administrator of the target company.  This call returns a list of all of the companies that the authenticated user is currently configured to be an administrator of.

EDIT:

```
/v1/companies?format=json&is-company-admin=true&start=1&count=1
```

should be :

```
/v1/companies?format=json&is-company-admin=true&count=1&start=1
```

you have to switch count with start

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need. Not sure though if ApiV2 replacement is correct, but I didn't find any better endpoint

Comment: i edited the answer with i think something that should help you.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help

Comment: thats weird, at my example it did work. could you show a bit of code and the api call you are trying to make.

Comment: `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies?format=json&is-company-admin=true&count=1&start=0"`

With this I get 
` "_count": 1,
  "_start": 0,
  "_total": 163

Changing start to 1 will result in   "_count": 1,
  "_start": 1,
  "_total": 163, but with he same values as in previous query

Comment: maybe dumb question because i dont have a 100+ business account but what happens if you just put in count:"163" start:"0"

Comment: `  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "The maximum number of companies to retrieve at once is 100",`

Comment: and what if you start at 100/101 ?

Comment: "values" are always the same
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1x2D5EfMLkaghZCWKOROKzxp3_1AfTdsM

Comment: I'm sorry Lars, what data are you talking about? I have 163 companies here and I don't see any way to get last 63 of them. What would I write to my code?

Comment: well the problem is that you arent getting the last 63. so a fix would be to manually add them. its not perfect but atleast you will have your list available until linkedin will fix this api. in the mean time try to get in contact with the linkedin dev's to ask for a solution.

because obviously the api is broken if you have a lot of companies.

Comment: I'm afraid this in not an option, since I need companies ids. I've tried to reach out anyone within LinkedIn Customer Support, but they've sent me to StackOverflow promising someone probably will answer someday

Comment: in the url from your company page there is an company id:

https://www.linkedin.com/company/987654321/admin/updates/

for the example i changed out alot of numbers but, the number-code is your companyid. so when you access the companypage as an admin you can see the company id.

Comment: I'm sorry for trying simplify my previous comment. I also need logo url, website url and number of followers. Adding all this stuff manually is not an option at all.

Comment: well i hope you get an answer, but i do not think anyone else but the linkedin devs can help you.